Chatbot using Transformer PyTorch is stuck at "I Don't Know" answer
I am trying to build a ChatBot using Transformer Architecture however even after many attempts with multiple changes in the hyperparameter and model etc the model is stuck. For every input the output is "I Dont Know".
Could someone please help? Below is the code.
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab,
                 d_model=512,
                 n_head=8,
                 num_encoder_layers=6,
                 num_decoder_layers=6,
                 dim_feedforward=2048,
                 dropout=0.1,
                 max_len=15) -> None:
        """Instantiating Transformer class
        Args:
            config (Config): model config, the instance of data_utils.utils.Config
            vocab (Vocabulary): the instance of data_utils.vocab_tokenizer.Vocabulary
        """
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()
        self.vocab = vocab
        d_model = d_model #512
        n_head = n_head #8
        num_encoder_layers = num_encoder_layers #6
        num_decoder_layers = num_decoder_layers #6
        dim_feedforward = dim_feedforward #2048
        dropout = dropout #0.1

        self.input_embedding = Embeddings(vocab, d_model, max_len)

        self.transfomrer = torch.nn.Transformer(d_model=d_model,
                                                nhead=n_head,
                                                num_encoder_layers=num_encoder_layers,
                                                num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers,
                                                dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward,
                                                dropout=dropout,
                                                batch_first=True)

        self.proj_vocab_layer = nn.Linear(in_features=d_model,
                                          out_features=len(vocab))

        # https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.apply
        self.apply(self._initailze)

    def forward(self, enc_input: torch.Tensor, dec_input: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:

        x_enc_embed = self.input_embedding(enc_input.long())
        x_dec_embed = self.input_embedding(dec_input.long())

        # Masking
        # tensor([[False, False, False,  True,  ...,  True]])
        src_key_padding_mask = enc_input == self.vocab["<pad>"]
        tgt_key_padding_mask = dec_input == self.vocab["<pad>"]

        memory_key_padding_mask = src_key_padding_mask
        tgt_mask = self.transfomrer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(dec_input.size(1))

        # transformer ref: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Transformer
        src_key_padding_mask = src_key_padding_mask.type(torch.float)
        tgt_key_padding_mask = tgt_key_padding_mask.type(torch.float)
        memory_key_padding_mask = memory_key_padding_mask.type(torch.float)
        tgt_mask = tgt_mask.type(torch.float).to(device)

        feature = self.transfomrer(src = x_enc_embed,
                                   tgt = x_dec_embed,
                                   src_key_padding_mask = src_key_padding_mask,
                                   tgt_key_padding_mask = tgt_key_padding_mask,
                                   memory_key_padding_mask=memory_key_padding_mask,
                                   tgt_mask = tgt_mask)

        logits = self.proj_vocab_layer(feature)
       
        return logits

    def _initailze(self, layer):
        if isinstance(layer, (nn.Linear)):
            nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(layer.weight)


class Embeddings(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab, embed_size, max_len):
        super(Embeddings, self).__init__()
        self.token_embedding = TokenEmbedding(vocab_size=len(vocab),
                                              embed_size=embed_size,
                                              pad_id=vocab["<pad>"])

        self.pos_embedding = PositionalEmbedding(d_model=embed_size,
                                                 max_len=max_len+2)

    def forward(self, x):
        token_embed = self.token_embedding(x)
        pos_embed = self.pos_embedding(x)

        # print(x.shape, token_embed.shape, pos_embed.shape)

        return token_embed + pos_embed

class PositionalEmbedding(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, d_model, max_len=512):
        super().__init__()

        # Compute the positional encodings once in log space.
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model).float()
        pe.require_grad = False

        position = torch.arange(0, max_len).float().unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = (torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model)).exp()

        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)

        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.pe[:, :x.size(1)]

Training Loop

d_model = 512  # also tried 32, 65, 128
n_head = 8
num_encoder_layers = 6
num_decoder_layers = num_encoder_layers
dim_feedforward = 2048
dropout = 0.1 # tried 0.5 as well

epochs = 10

transformer = Transformer(word_map,
                 d_model=d_model,
                 n_head=n_head,
                 num_encoder_layers=num_encoder_layers,
                 num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers,
                 dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward,
                 dropout=dropout,
                 max_len=15).to(device)

adam_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(transformer.parameters(), lr=0.00, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)
transformer_optimizer = AdamWarmup(model_size=512, warmup_steps = 4000, optimizer = adam_optimizer)
criterion = LossWithLS(len(word_map), 0.1)

for epoch in range(epochs):

    transformer.train()
    sum_loss = 0
    count = 0

    for i, (enc_inp, dec_inp, dec_out) in enumerate(train_loader):

        samples = enc_inp.shape[-1]

        # Move to device
        enc_inp = enc_inp.to(device)
        dec_inp, dec_out = dec_inp.to(device), dec_out.to(device)

        # Get the transformer outputs
        out = transformer(enc_inp, dec_inp)

        # Compute the loss
        # print(out.shape, reply_target.shape)
        loss = criterion(out, dec_out)

        # Backprop
        transformer_optimizer.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        transformer_optimizer.step()

        sum_loss += loss.item() * samples
        # print(loss.item(),  samples)
        count += samples

        if i % (batch_size * 5) == 0:
            # print(loss.item(),  samples)
            print("Epoch [{}][{}/{}]\tLoss: {:.3f}".format(epoch, i, len(train_loader), sum_loss/count))
            getResults(transformer)

    state = {'epoch': epoch, 'transformer': transformer, 'transformer_optimizer': transformer_optimizer}
    # torch.save(state, 'checkpoint_' + str(epoch) + '.pth.tar')


Lastly dataset is cornell movie dialogs and I am preprossing the dataset to have PAD, BOS and EOS. I tried chaing the vocab size from 23k to 5k but did not help. I tried changing the number of instances in the dataset with not work, it just always gets stuck at I dont know. Has anyone tried any such thing?
corpus_movie_conv = '/content/drive/My Drive/AI/cornell movie-dialogs corpus/movie_conversations.txt'
corpus_movie_lines = '/content/drive/My Drive/AI/cornell movie-dialogs corpus/movie_lines.txt'


The learning rate is 0.0 in your adam optimizer, is that a typo?

No, learning rate starts with 0 and with every step the rate goes up and then down depending upon the warmup class.

The learning rate of 0 is very probably preventing your program from learning. I understand that you have a warmup scheduler, but try setting it to at least something like 0.0001

I have tried that as well. 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001 did not help. always converges to  I Dont know
